# CoovaChilli & FreeRadius: Apache server Authentication

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, radius, freeradius, coovachilli

- **What I'm using:**

  1. Ubiquiti AirRouter
  2. CoovaChilli
  3. AWS server with FreeRadius & Apache2
- **What I'm trying:**

  1. Set up a ***captive portal*** using the **Ubiquiti AirRouter**
  2. Use ***CoovaChilli*** firmware to set up captive portal on **Ubiquiti**
  3. Make the radius authentification with the FreeRadiusServer on AWS
  4. Use ***apache2*** server on AWS to create the web captive portal for the user to log in

I have the Ubiquiti AirRouter configured with the CoovaChilli firmware (no issues here). The AP generated by the router works as expected and when you try to see any page, you get redirected to the apache web server.

- **Where I'm stuck:**

  The communication between the captive portal and the router is my issue. I'm trying to use *ChilliLibrary.js* functions (**ChilliJSON**) to make the radius login but it seems I'm missing some configuration, the response I get when I'm trying to authenticate in the captive portal is:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:1812/json/status?callback=chilliJSON.reply&0.2522223754785955net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
ChilliLibrary.js:531
```

---

I'm looking for information in CoovaChilli and Chilli documentation but cannot find anything helpfull here.

- Anybody knows any good tutorial about this part of a captive portal ? The connection between the webserver and the router ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED tells all. Just check your netstat output and verify that your able to get through any firewalls with netcat.

Answer (score 1):

GET http://127.0.0.1:1812/ and net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED says it all.

Check that you have a service running on port 1812 of localhost with netstat -ntl | grep 1812 then double check your firewall is allowing traffic through port 1812.

Answer (score -2):

This may be of some use if you have not come across it before.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/CoovaChilli

Comment: Thanks but that's the first tutorial I followed. My issue now is with **ChilliJSON**, the connection between the captive portal and the freeradius server